# yii xupload mysql for CActiveForm

Tags: yii, upload, blueimp, yii-xupload

I am trying to include xupload extension for yii in the CActiveForm I try to follow this http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/395/additional-form-data-with-xupload/ 
However I cannot make it. I have a form which has the field of username and filename (allow user to upload and view it from the view.)
this is my view

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
      'id' => 'form-form',
      'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        //This is very important when uploading files
      'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    ));
  ?>    
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Other Fields... -->
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'attachment_photo'); ?>
        <?php
    $this->widget('xupload.XUpload', array(
        'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("form/uploadAdditional", array("parent_id" => 1)),
        'model' => $model,//An instance of our model
        'attribute' => 'file',
        'multiple' => true,
        //Our custom upload template
        'uploadView' => 'application.views.site.upload',
        //our custom download template
        'downloadView' => 'application.views.site.download',
        'options' => array(//Additional javascript options
            //This is the submit callback that will gather
            //the additional data  corresponding to the current file
            'submit' => "js:function (e, data) {
                var inputs = data.context.find(':input');
                data.formData = inputs.serializeArray();
                return true;
            }"
        ),
    ));
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing is what your $_POST array looks like. (Check this with Firebug, or Fiddler).

Your $_POST should look like this:

```
array (
  'form-form' => array ( /* stuff for additional form data */)),
  'XupLoad' => array ( /* stuff pertaining to XuLoad */)),
)
```

In this way, the additional form data is separate from the XupLoad data. The action as included in the Xupload extension handles the `$_POST['XupLoad']` part of the array. You will have to write code to handle the `$_POST['form-form']` part of the array.

By the way, Blueimp's jQuery File Upload has a new version with important improvements and bug-fixes. It does not look like the XupLoad extension includes this latest version.

I would suggest going with Blueimp's latest version. It has an UploadHandler class that takes care of everything server-side. The latest version is really well written. You will still have to add code for handling the additional form data...

**afterthought**: It looks like you are nesting your widgets. I am not sure that this could work. Check the page source in your browser. Make sure that the HTML generated is sound. It could be that you are generating nested forms, and I have my doubts about how those would work.

Comment: thanks a lot.. i will try the blueimp's latest version see how it works =)

Comment: i couldn't make it so i stick back to basic upload. Do you have any idea that i can integrate the yii booster progressbar to the yii basic file upload?

Comment: No, I am not familiar with Yii booster progressbar. However, I believe it is impossible to add a progressbar to a basic file upload, because there is simply no progress-information available. Do you have a live site that you want to integrate File Uploader into? And: what functionality are you looking for: chuncked uploads, progressbar, preview of images? (I integrated jQuery FileUploader last week, and it took my a full (12 hours) day ...)

Answer (score 0):

this is my live testing site. http://vincentlkl.allalla.com/ the form i have already enctype to mulitpart

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'form-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
'stateful'=>true, 
'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')
```

)); ?>

/**the fileupload widget**/

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbFileUpload', array(
'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("form/upload"),
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'file',
        'multiple' => true,
        'options' => array(
            'maxFileSize' => 3000000,
            'acceptFileTypes' => "js:/(\.|\/)(jpe?g|png)$/i",
        )

));
 ?>
```

I cannot upload the file when it's in the form.

Comment: OK. If you look at the page source, there are two, nested forms. I think that is a problem. This could be the reason that when you hit *start uploads* your XHR request crashes (Firebug reports back with *0 requests*). I will show a working HTML form in my next answer:

Comment: sorry i am not really sure what did u mean. Is it making two forms into one? i have removed the one in form.php(fileupload temp) i try to view source in firebug it shows only one form. is that what you mean? thanks a lot =)

Comment: OK, I see you have one form now. That is good. However, you chose *form-form*. Choose the other form, the one that belongs to jQuery File Upload. Right now, *.fileuploader()* is missing the <form> to initialize. You need to generate one form, with a tag like so: *<form id="fileupload" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">* jQuery File Uploader needs this to get started.

Comment: If you can't get it to work, just start with the jQuery File Upload demo. Leave out your extra form data. First get it to work with your server, so you can actually upload files. Only then, add an '<input>' field. See what your $_POST looks like. If it looks OK, then write the handling of that one field on the server-side...

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, forget about the widgets you are calling. Below is the an example of the HTML that should be generated, in order to combine jQuery FileUpload with other form fields:

```
<!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
<form id="fileupload" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="Input_upload[titleInArchive]" id="Input_upload_titleInArchive" type="text" />   

    <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="span7">
            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                <span>Start upload</span>
            </button>
    <!-- the rest of the demo jQuery File upload page ... -->
</form>
```

This form has one input field **titleInArchive** which co-exists with the jQuery File Upload form. The `<input>` is located inside the jQuery File Upload  tags. So in your case, you would put the extra `<input>`'s inside the `$this->widget('xupload.XUpload', ...)`

Once you have done this, hit the start upload button. In Firebug, check the XHR request. What does the $_POST array look like? In your case, it should be something like

```
$_POST['Form']['username'] ...
$_POST['Form']['identity_card'] ...
```

I hope I am making sense ...

Comment: thanks a lot i think i get the XHR 0request part whereby the jquery fileupload form is crash with the form. Does it mean i need to add FormView ?

Comment: Not sure. What is FormView?